# How to display one value array if data array same value Recylerview android

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview

if i have data array :

**[Megi,Megi,Jhon,Luke,Luke,Thoni,Jhon**]

and i want to display in listview, how to filter the same value just one data to show?

hmmm maybe output like this :

**Megi, Jhon, Luke, Thoni, Jhon**

Just one data to display if same value

this is my code to set value to TextView :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedsCustomAdapterUser.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Feeds feed = getFeeds().get(position);


        holder.userName.setText(feed.user.fullName);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(feed.user.avatar)
                .into(holder.profileUser);

    }
```

Comment: you want to avoid duplicates?

Comment: The adapter acts as if its in a for loop. What you need to do is manually exlude the indexes in the adapter. Or never add them to array list to begin with.

Comment: You can use `HASHSET`

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with displaying them into the container, what you are asking is how you filter out duplicates from a collection. As simple as it gets, use a collection that doesn't accept duplicates (for instance a Set will do in your case), before you set the data collection into the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to remove repeated elements is to add the contents to a Set (which will not allow duplicates) and then add the Set back to the ArrayList

you this in your MainActivity

```
 ArrayList<String> sampleArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
 HashSet<String> ArrayList2 = new HashSet<String>();
 ArrayList2.addAll(sampleArrayList);
 sampleArrayList.clear();
 sampleArrayList.addAll(ArrayList2);
```

Comment: what is addAll?

Comment: @MegiFernanda 

The java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) method appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator

Comment: @MegiFernanda did you get your ans..?

Comment: i can't use addAll sir

Comment: @MegiFernanda why u can't use addall

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort list first. And compare adjacent elements, if duplicates found remove it from list.

Answer (score 1):

Well u can solve this easily by using a Linked Hash set:

```
 ArrayList<String> sampleArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();//array of strings

LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<>(sampleArrayList);//all duplicates removed
```

Comment: so i its will be `lhs.add(data)` or sampleArrayList.add(data) and when i call my data using `lhs`, right?